# ReadByte function does it work correctly

Tags: c#

In `FileStream` class we have `ReadByte` method well actually it does not work as I supposed
why `ReadByte` ignore "nonsignificant" zeros from beginning of byte? How could I avoid that ?

as someone mentioned in comments, yes im trying to convert it to string

```
dane.Append(Convert.ToString((byte)w,2));
```

So is it ToString function skipping zeros?

Comment: please elaborate, show some code to reproduce the problem...

Comment: A byte is a byte is a byte. What do you think it is skipping? Example byte contents (from the file), and what you are expecting: would help.

Comment: Your question is unclear. `ReadByte` does exactly as it says.. reads a single byte.

Comment: The only unusual property of `ReadByte` is that it returns -1 at the end of the file. Else it returns the byte as an integer. Integers don't have a concept of leading zeros.

Comment: I wonder if this is an endianness problem when working with a larger data-type. For example, writing `1` as a 4-byte int32 can write **either** 0x00000001 *or* 0x01000000

Comment: CodeslnChaos answered why its skipping, well if we have byte number 85 so in 2_base it woudl be 01010101, but after using ReadByte its 1010101

Comment: @whd you are obviously using something to convert it to a string

Comment: Those are two different ways to write the same number, whd. You can write the number any way you want, it's still the same number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The numbers are the same; only the ToString is the issue

```
dane.Append(Convert.ToString((byte)w,2).PadLeft(8, '0'));
```

Answer (score 1):

`ReadByte` reads a byte. The result it returns is a *number*. When you say "nonsignificant zeroes", presumably you mean zero *digits*. But digits are not properties of numbers, they're properties of textual depictions of numbers in base ten (or sixteen).

"8" and "08" are two different ways to depict in digits the *same* number. If you aren't seeing the number depicted the way you want it, the issue is in the code that chose who to depict it.